# How to change size of canvas in libavg?

Tags: python-2.7, canvas, libavg

I'm going to build a player with Libavg. How can I change the size of canvas in such a way it automatically fits the video size?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that after you've started playback. What you can do is create the video node before playback, query it's size and create an appropriately-sized canvas:

```
class VideoPlayer(app.MainDiv):

    def __init__(self):
        self.node = avg.VideoNode(href="video.h264")
        self.node.pause()
        size = self.node.getMediaSize()
        self.settings.set("app_resolution", "%dx%d" %(size.x, size.y))
```